# What is the "mintsystem" service setting and when would I want to activate it?

Tags: linux-mint, startup, services

In hunting around my GUI for a place to enable sshd I clicked on "Services" from the Administration section of the Linux Mint (16) menu.

It opened a window titled "Service Settings" and inside it I came across a service called "mintsystem".  Googling / Duck Duck Going produced references to the package, but no good descriptions of function.  What does this service do?  When would I want to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are scripts that reside in `/etc/init.d`. Looking there, I saw a file called `mintsystem` with the following contents:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ cat /etc/init.d/mintsystem 
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mintsystem
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs dbus
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:  
### END INIT INFO

/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSystem/mint-adjust.py
```

So, this service, when started, simply runs a python script. The script itself is very simple, it just sets up various things that basically mintify mint.

You can see what it does and if it's ever been run by checking its log file `/var/log/mintsystem.log`. Reading through it, you will see that it applies the Mint artwork for firefox, it copies over Mint's basic defaults files for things like the login manager and `gnome-panel` and sets the contents of `/etc/os-release` etc.

Basically, it is a simple housekeeping script that is probably run automatically in the background whenever needed by the system. After an upgrade perhaps? In any case, you don't really care about it and you don't need to activate it.